# Importing Classes from Separate Files

Tags: python, class, import, module

So I'm working on familiarizing myself with object oriented programming by messing around with classes in python.  Below is a simple code I [tried] to implement in just the interpreter.

```
class Test(object):

    def set_name(self, _name):
        name = _name

    def set_age(self, _age):
        age = _age

    def set_weight(self, _weight):
        weight = _weight

    def set_height(self, _height):
        height = _height
```

When I start up python, I run the following commands:

```
>>>import Test
>>>Test.set_name("Sean")
```

and then I receive this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_name'
```

I am basing this all off of the official module documentation found [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#modules).

I have read quite a bit of documentation on OOP, but I am still very new, so I'm sure there's still something going right over my head.  What does that error mean?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you're importing the *module* `Test`. Do you have a class called `Test` inside a module called `Test`?

If so, you need to import the class directly as `from Test import Test` or, if you just want to import the module, you need to refer to your class as `Test.Test`.

EDIT: About the `unbound method set_name()` error. You need call the `set_name` method on class instance and not directly on the class. `Test().set_name("Sean")` will work (notice the `()` after the `Test` which creates the instance).

The set name method expects an instance of the class `Test` as a first argument (`self`). So the method will raise an error if it is not called on  an instance. There are ways of calling it directly from a class by explicitly supplying instance as  the first parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  I guess I'm not really positive as to what the answer to your question is.  I just have a file called Test.py, and in that file is the code posted above.  Based on the module documentation I linked to above, I think I do indeed have a class within a module.  However, when I replace `import Test` with `from Test import Test`, I get this error:

    `Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: unbound method set_name() must be called with Test     instance as first argument (got str instance instead)`

Comment: Thanks again for the quick reply!  Your advice worked, and I am able to use the set_name() method without error.